# Using Reflection To Instantiate 'Builder Pattern' (Joshua Bloch)

Tags: reflection, builder

When attempting to use Joshua Bloch's "Builder Pattern" [Item 2 in *Effective Java Second Edition*] with reflection [**object = constructors[index].newInstance(constructorParameterValues);**] the following exception occurs:

java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class info.soaj.core.util.SjUtilReflection can not access a member of class info.soaj.core.attribute.SjAttributesForThrowable with modifiers "private"

Note: This has been resolved.  The accessible (private) constructor was being discarded and a non-accessible (override = false) was being attempted.  Bottom Line: Programmer Error

An example Builder Class follows:

```
package info.soaj.core.attribute;

import info.soaj.core.attribute.internal.SjAttributesForStronglyTypedWrappers;
import info.soaj.core.internal.string.SjPopulatedClassName;
import info.soaj.core.internal.string.SjPopulatedMethodName;
import info.soaj.core.util.internal.SjUtilThrowable;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * <p>
 * The "Builder" pattern as documented by Joshua Bloch ("Effective Java" -
 * Second Edition) is utilized to handle the variable number of required and
 * optional parameters.
 * </p>
 * 
 * <p style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:10px; font-style:italic"> Copyright
 * (c) 2006 - 2008 by Global Technology Consulting Group, Inc. at <a
 * href="http://gtcGroup.com">gtcGroup.com </a>. </p>
 * 
 * @author MarvinToll@gtcGroup.com
 * @since v. 1.0
 */

public class SjAttributesExample implements Serializable {

    /** UID */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The name of class throwing the exception. */
    protected final SjPopulatedClassName classname;

    /** The name of method throwing the exception. */
    protected final SjPopulatedMethodName methodname;

    /**
     * Suppresses logging; default is <code>false</code>.
     */
    protected final boolean suppressLoggingOnly;

    /**
     * Constructor - private
     * 
     * @param builderThrowable
     */
    private SjAttributesExample(final BuilderThrowable builderThrowable) {
        this.classname = builderThrowable.classname;
        this.methodname = builderThrowable.methodname;
        this.suppressLoggingOnly = builderThrowable.suppressLoggingOnly;
    }

    /**
     * This static member immutable class is used to implement the builder
     * pattern.
     * 
     * @author MarvinToll@gtcGroup.com
     * @since v. 1.0
     */
    public static class BuilderThrowable {

        /** Class name. */
        private static final String CLASS_NAME = BuilderThrowable.class
                .getName();

        // Required attributes.

        /** The name of class throwing the exception. */
        protected final SjPopulatedClassName classname;

        /** The name of method throwing the exception. */
        protected final SjPopulatedMethodName methodname;

        // Optional attributes.

        /** Prevents action from occurring. Default is false. */
        protected boolean suppressLoggingOnly = false;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * 
         * @param classname
         * @param methodname
         */
        public BuilderThrowable(final String classname, final String methodname) {

            super();

            final String Method_Name = "BuilderThrowable";

            // What happens when handling an exception throws an exception?
            try {

                this.classname = new SjPopulatedClassName(classname,
                        new SjAttributesForStronglyTypedWrappers(CLASS_NAME,
                                Method_Name));

                this.methodname = new SjPopulatedMethodName(methodname,
                        new SjAttributesForStronglyTypedWrappers(CLASS_NAME,
                                Method_Name));

            } catch (final RuntimeException e) {

                // Log the contextual details.
                SjUtilThrowable.logExceptionOccuredWhileThrowingException(
                        CLASS_NAME, Method_Name, e);

                throw e;
            }

            return;
        }

        /**
         * This method sets a flag to suppress logging.
         * 
         * @param isLoggingSuppressed
         * @return BuilderThrowable
         */
        public BuilderThrowable suppressLoggingOnly(
                final boolean isLoggingSuppressed) {

            this.suppressLoggingOnly = isLoggingSuppressed;

            return this;
        }

        /**
         * This method is used for instantiating this class.
         * 
         * @return SjAttributesForThrowable
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
        public SjAttributesExample build() {

            return new SjAttributesExample(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method returns an attribute.
     * 
     * @return String - Returns the <code>classname</code> attribute.
     */
    public String getClassname() {
        return this.classname.getString();
    }

    /**
     * This method returns an attribute.
     * 
     * @return String - Returns the <code>methodname</code> attribute.
     */
    public String getMethodname() {
        return this.methodname.getString();
    }

    /**
     * This method returns an attribute.
     * 
     * @return boolean - Returns the <code>suppressLoggingOnly</code> attribute.
     */
    public boolean isLoggingSuppressed() {
        return this.suppressLoggingOnly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This has been resolved. The accessible (private) constructor was being discarded and a non-accessible (override = false) was being attempted. Bottom Line: Programmer Error